# Good time to shutdown Postgres server

Tags: postgresql

PG when doing a clean shutdown calls postmaster to cleanly stop everything.
This means postmaster might take the checkpoint, archive and upload WAL files etc.

This can be a time consuming job. I want to know if there is a way to see how many (or size of) WAL files need to archived before sending the kill command to PG.

Is there a way to know/predict the time taken by PG stop by querying some pg tables?

Answer (score 2):

Archiving is not your problem here, because WAL segments are filled one after the other and archived right when they are full. Also, there is no spike in WAL activity during a shutdown. There is only one final WAL segment that gets archived once the shutdown checkpoint is done.

What can take some time is the checkpoint that is executed during shutdown. There is a trick to speed that up: run an explicit checkpoint right before shutdown. Then the final checkpoint will have little to do and can finish quickly:

```bash
# explicit checkpoint to speed up the shutdown
psql -c CHECKPOINT
# shutdown the PostgreSQL server
pg_ctl stop
```